# NFS Manager 5.1 won't run on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: mac, macos-catalina

I just updated my OS from High Sierra to Catalina. I had NFS Manager installed and working. When I tried to run it in Catalina, it said my NFS Manager version was too old, and told me to update.

I went and downloaded the latest NFS Manager (5.1), and as soon as the DMG mounts, it shows this:

[image: NFS Manager Error 1]

and if I try to run it, it says this:

[image: NFS Manager Error 2]

I'm having a hard time believing that a few days after macOS 11 came out, NFS Manager released an update that only allows it to run on macOS 11, and not any older OS's. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging, I finally noticed that it says the latest version of NFS Manager requires macOS 11.0 Big Sur, and there's a tiny link that points to older versions that work on older OS's. The page is here: https://www.bresink.com/osx/LegacyProducts.html.